# How to extend MS Health Bot existing scenarios?

Tags: botframework

I am evaluating MS Health Bot service and able to create and test custom scenarios. However, I was looking at extending existing in-built scenario like "I have a headache" and customize based on my need. I could see product features say we can extend existing scenarios but I don't see any documentation on how to do it. Anyone aware of how to extend existing scenario?

Thanks
Monu

**Additional Information:**
Health Bot Service provided three templates in the catalog - Provider Lookup, File a claim, Handoff to a human. There are few others with Coming Soon tag.

[Scenarios template catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvhWJ.png)

However, I thought, I can use any of the already trained bot scenario to handle medical conditions like "I have a headache" as shown in the diagram below.(which shows up in empty designer page on the right chat widget)

[Demo chat for "I have a headache"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6r21.png)

So my revised question is "we will be able to extend only scenario that is part of template catalog and our own created scenario". Is that correct understanding?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you import the "I have a headache" scenario from?

Comment: Well when I go to inbuilt demo chat option  and type "I have a headache", the built in bot response with different options. So the question was can I extend the scenario that handle "I have headache" medical condition. For your information, I know how to extend scenario from template in catalog. But I was wandering if there is a way to extend default bot responses which is not part of template

Comment: It appears that you only able to modify the three templates in the catalog and not scenarios like I have a headache. I have updated my answer below to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize pre-built scenarios in the Healthcare Bot through the Scenario Designer. In the Healthcare bot service you created, click on Manage Account. If you do not have any scenarios configured, either select a template scenario or create a new blank scenario. Otherwise, click on the name of the scenario to open the designer. From here, you can customize the scenario as needed by either adding more scenario elements from the top pane or modifying elements in the scenario.

[image]

At the moment it appears that you are only able to modify the three provided templates. You do not have access to the other scenarios like 'I have a headache' in the healthcare manager. The Healthcare Bot Service is relatively new so that might change in future updates.

I would recommend looking at the topics under Scenario Authoring in the [Healthcare Bot Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/scenario-authoring/scenario_management) for more details on creating and editing scenarios.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @tdurnford. I have added additional information. Can you please confirm?